# Migrate resources from Terraform to Serverless Framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

We have a cloudformation stack that was previously deployed with Terraform. We are now using Serverless framework instead. We have recreated the resource definitions in serverless.yml but we can't deploy this as the resources already exist with the same names.

Is there a way to migrate the resources that already exist to the serverless deployment?

Answer (score 0):

The answer it seems, is no. At least, nothing vaguely automated. However there are manual steps that can be performed to achieve this as documented on the AWS docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/refactor-stacks.html